# reshape an array of images

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

I have 60000 train_images brought in as a shape (28,28,60000) matrix. It is a numpy.ndarray. I want to convert it to an array of 1 dimensional images, meaning each image is represented as a single line/array of numbers, and I want 60000 arrays. In other words, I want to go from (28, 28, 60000) to (60000, 28*28). In python, it would be:

```
images_features = []
for image in images:
    imageLine = []
    for y in range(len(image)):
        for x in range(len(image[0])):
            imageLine.append(image[y][x])
    images_features.append(imageLine)
```

How can I do this? I suspect that I need to use reshape but I couldn't figure out how exactly I can do this.

This is how I'm getting the images:

```
data = scipy.io.loadmat('train.mat')


images = data["train_images"]
```

So the "images" is the array I'm talking about.

Someone suggested to me that:

"You may need to change axes or combine them do get the functionality you want.  I recommend plotting them as well in case an image ends up sideways.  Make sure you are diligent with your axes to avoid further problems there."

I have no idea what "axes" is being referred to here and how to take what's said above into account.

**Can someone explain what I need to do and why? (What it does)**

Comment: Maybe `images.reshape(-1).tolist()` if you want the output to be a python list (or without `tolist()` otherwise)?

Comment: What does the -1 do? I need a 1 by 28^2 by 60000 array.

Comment: Well sorry i misreaded. the `-1` flatten completely the matrix (which is not what you want). You can take a look at the numpy documentation about [`N-dimensional array`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html)

Comment: If I understand well, `images.reshape(-1, 60000)` will do the job ? Giving you 60000 features with 784 values. To have the output as a python list of 60000 features : `images.reshape(-1, 60000).T.tolist()`

Comment: `image.transpose(2,0,1)` or `image.transpose(2,1,0)`?

Comment: You mean AFTER the reshape? Why would that be needed here? @Divakar

Comment: I mean to go from `(28, 28, 60000)` to `(60000, 28*28)` one of those two should work. And NO reshape needed.

Comment: The shape after either of the two transposes is still (60000, 28, 28) , not (60000, 28*28), where, for each image, one row is concatenated to the end of the previous row, resulting in one row per image, 60000 rows in total. @Divakar

Comment: So, try `image.transpose(2,0,1).reshape(60000,-1)` and `image.transpose(2,1,0).reshape(60000,-1)`. One of these two 
should work.

Comment: Thanks, image.transpose(2,1,0).reshape(60000,-1) works! @Divakar

Comment: Alternatively, just image.transpose().reshape(60000, -1), with the default transpose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since this is coming via `loadmat`, a shape of `(28,28,60000)` makes sense - MATLAB iterates starting with the last index.

```
images.transpose()  # or images.T
```

reorders the axes, so the result is `(60000,28,28)`.  The last two dimensions can combined with a reshape

```
images.T.reshape(60000,28*28)
images.T.reshape(60000,-1)   # short hand
```

You many need to transpose the 28x28 images, e.g.

```
images.transpose([2,0,1])  # instead of the default [2,1,0]
```

`.T` is the same as the MATLAB `'` (or `.'`).

`images` may also be `order='F'`.

---

```
octave:38> images=reshape(1:30,2,3,5);
octave:39> save test.mat -v7 images
octave:40> images
images =

ans(:,:,1) =

   1   3   5
   2   4   6

ans(:,:,2) =

    7    9   11
    8   10   12
....
```

I chose test dimensions to be small, and to make it easy to distinguish the different axes.

In a Ipython session:

```
In [15]: data=io.loadmat('test.mat')

In [16]: data
Out[16]: 
{'__globals__': [],
 '__header__': 'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, written by Octave 3.8.2, 2016-02-10 05:19:18 UTC',
 '__version__': '1.0',
 'images': array([[[  1.,   7.,  13.,  19.,  25.],
        [  3.,   9.,  15.,  21.,  27.],
        [  5.,  11.,  17.,  23.,  29.]],

       [[  2.,   8.,  14.,  20.,  26.],
        [  4.,  10.,  16.,  22.,  28.],
        [  6.,  12.,  18.,  24.,  30.]]])}

In [18]: data['images'].T
Out[18]: 
array([[[  1.,   2.],
        [  3.,   4.],
        [  5.,   6.]],

       [[  7.,   8.],
        [  9.,  10.],
        [ 11.,  12.]],
....
In [19]: data['images'].transpose([2,0,1])
Out[19]: 
array([[[  1.,   3.,   5.],
        [  2.,   4.,   6.]],

       [[  7.,   9.,  11.],
        [  8.,  10.,  12.]],
 ....
In [22]: data['images'].transpose([2,1,0]).reshape(5,-1)
Out[22]: 
array([[  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   6.],
       [  7.,   8.,   9.,  10.,  11.,  12.],
 ...
```

Comment: So I do: images = images.transpose().reshape(60000, -1)?

Comment: If so, how do I decide whether to use the default transpose vs the 2, 0, 1?

Comment: So, from the example above, it seems like data['images'].transpose([2,1,0]).reshape(5,-1) does the right thing, where the 2,1,0 is the default setting for transpose.

Answer (score 4):

I think you just need to use reshape:

```
>>> images = np.ndarray([60000, 28, 28])
>>> images.shape
(60000, 28, 28)
>>> images_rs = images.reshape([60000, 28*28])
>>> images_rs.shape
(60000, 784)
```

Comment: Should it be images.reshape([60000, 28*28]) or images.reshape([28*28, 60000])? What is the difference?

Comment: In my comments I used a shape of `28, 28, 60000` just to fit the number you said in your question but `reshape` wont complains as the size of the array isn't changed (and the output is probably more ordered as you want using `60000, 28*28` instead of `28*28, 60000`).

Comment: I think if you have 60000 individual images, then that should be the first dimension. You will have an array containing 60000 arrays of length 784. In the (28*28 x 60000) case you will have an array containing 784 (28*28) arrays of length 60000.

Comment: It turns out that the way suggested in the answer doesn't work correctly.

Comment: The size of the resulting matrix is correct but the content isn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can reshape `train_images` and verify it by plotting the images,

Reshaping:

```
train_features_images = train_images.reshape(train_images.shape[0],28,28)
```

Plotting images:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def show_images(features_images,labels,start, howmany):
    for i in range(start, start+howmany):
        plt.figure(i)
        plt.imshow(features_images[i], cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'))
        plt.title(labels[i])
    plt.show()
show_images(train_features_images, labels, 1, 10)
```