# Images get distorted after splitting the array using scikit-learn

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I have a `.mat` file that contains an array of `600` `24*21` images. Hence the resulting dimension is `(24, 21, 600)`. The following code would show the images in subplots:

```
X = loadmat('../input/data.mat')['face']
# generate dummy labels for this example
y = np.concatenate([np.zeros(300), np.ones(300)])

# X.shape == (24, 21, 600)
# y.shape == (600,)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(4,5)

for i, axis in enumerate(ax.flat):
    axis.imshow(X[:,:,i], cmap='bone')
    axis.set(xticks=[], yticks=[])
```

That is fine. The problem is when I try to split the data into train and test data using:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y,
    random_state=42,
    test_size=0.2,
    shuffle=True
)
```

An error occurs:

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [24, 600]
```

I know the error is that the first dimension of my `X` and `y` are not matching. But if I try to reshape `X` using `X = X.reshape(600, 24, 21)` such that `X.shape === (600, 24, 21)`, the shapes are fixed I can successfully split the data using `train_test_split()`

However, now when I try to make subplots using the code below:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(4,5)

for i, axis in enumerate(ax.flat):
    axis.imshow(X[i,:,:], cmap='bone')
    axis.set(xticks=[], yticks=[])
```

The images make no sense and are changed. I cannot make a classifier using these images. Can anyone help me out?

1. In the best case, how do I split the data without having to reshape?
2. How do I not distort my images after reshaping them and successfully splitting the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the sample axis is in position 2 instead of 0. Sklearn then thinks that you have 24 samples of shape `(21, 600)`.
you want `X.shape` to be `(600, 24, 21)` and not `(24, 21, 600)`.

So, you can use [np.rollaxis](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.rollaxis.html) to change the positions:

```
X = np.rollaxis(X, 2, 0)
```

Comment: Although I used `X = X.transpose([2, 0, 1])`,  your solution is likely going to work as well. In fact, my question is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35302361/reshape-an-array-of-images) question.