# Convert 3d numpy array into a 2d numpy array (where contents are tuples)

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following 3d numpy array `np.random.rand(6602, 3176, 2)`.
I would like to convert it to a 2d array (`numpy` or `pandas.DataFrame`), where each value inside is a tuple, such that the shape is `(6602, 3176)`.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32838802/numpy-with-python-convert-3d-array-to-2d) questioned helped me see how to decrease the dimensions, but I still struggle with the tuple bit.

Comment: I think I have a better question: why would you want that? Strictly speaking, what you are asking would require you to use a NumPy array of type `object`, but it is not a good use-case for the problem you seems to be dealing with. Perhaps you are running into the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? However, for most practical purposes, sticking to the 3D array and figuring a smart way of using the `axis` parameter of NumPy functions is probably the way to go.

Comment: @norok2 you may very well be right. Maybe I should rethink a more elegant solution to it. Thanks, the link is interesting to read.

Comment: "where each value inside is a tuple, such that the shape is (6602, 3176)." can you please rephrase that statement.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a one-liner which takes a few seconds on the full (6602, 3176, 2) problem

```
a = np.random.rand(6602, 3176, 2)

b = a.view([(f'f{i}',a.dtype) for i in range(a.shape[-1])])[...,0].astype('O')
```

The trick here is to viewcast to a compund dtype which spans exactly one row. When such a compound dtype is then cast on to object each compound element is converted to a tuple.

**UPDATE** (hat tip @hpaulj) there is a library function that does precisely the view casting we do manually: `numpy.lib.recfunctions.unstructured_to_structured`

Using this we can write a more readable version of the above:

```
import numpy.lib.recfunctions as nlr

b = nlr.unstructured_to_structured(a).astype('O')
```

Comment: Very elegant! One question: why `f'f{i}'` instead of just `str(i)`?

Comment: @norok2 force of habit I suppose.

Comment: `numpy.lib.recfunctions.unstructured_to_structured` is the new recommended tool for converting an array to a structured dtype.  In this case it just eliminates the need for that `[...,0]` step.  `unstructured_to_structured(a)` is enough.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to do, what you want to do, you have to set `dtype` of you array to `object`. E.g., if you have the mentioned array:

```
a = np.random.rand(6602, 3176, 2)
```

You could create a second empty array with shape (6602, 3176) and set `dtype` to `object`:

```
b = np.empty(a[:,:,0].shape, dtype=object)
```

and fill your array with tuples.

But in the end there is no big advantage! I'd just use slicing to get the tuples from your initial array `a`. You can just access the tuples of indexes `n` (1st dimension) and `m` (2nd dimension) and forget about the third dimension and slice your 3d array:

```
a[n,m,:]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy with `list` instead of `tuple`, this could be achieved with the following trick:

1. convert your array to `list` of `list`s using `.tolist()`
2. make sure that you change the size of one of the innermost `list` (misalign)
3. convert the `list` of `list`s back to NumPy array
4. fix the modification of point 2.

This is implemented in the following function `last_dim_as_list()`:

```py
import numpy as np


def last_dim_as_list(arr):
    if arr.ndim > 1:
        # : convert to list of lists
        arr_list = arr.tolist()
        # : misalign size of the first innermost list
        temp = arr_list
        for _ in range(arr.ndim - 1):
            temp = temp[0]
        temp.append(None)
        # : convert to NumPy array
        # (uses `object` because of the misalignment)
        result = np.array(arr_list)
        # : revert the misalignment
        temp.pop()
    else:
        result = np.empty(1, dtype=object)
        result[0] = arr.tolist()
    return result

np.random.seed(0)
in_arr = np.random.randint(0, 9, (2, 3, 2))
out_arr = last_dim_as_list(in_arr)


print(in_arr)
# [[[5 0]
#   [3 3]
#   [7 3]]
#  [[5 2]
#   [4 7]
#   [6 8]]]
print(in_arr.shape)
# (2, 3, 2)
print(in_arr.dtype)
# int64

print(out_arr)
# [[list([5, 0]) list([3, 3]) list([7, 3])]
#  [list([5, 2]) list([4, 7]) list([6, 8])]]
print(out_arr.shape)
# (2, 3)
print(out_arr.dtype)
# object
```

However, I would **NOT** recommend taking this route unless you really know what you are doing.
Most of the time you are better off by keeping everything as a NumPy array of higher dimensionality, and make good use of [NumPy indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html).

---

Note that this could also be done with explicit loops, but the proposed approach should be much faster for large enough inputs:

```py
def last_dim_as_list_loop(arr):
    shape = arr.shape
    result = np.empty(arr.shape[:-1], dtype=object).ravel()
    for k in range(arr.shape[-1]):
        for i in range(result.size):
            if k == 0:
                result[i] = []
            result[i].append(arr[..., k].ravel()[i])
    return result.reshape(shape[:-1])


out_arr2 = last_dim_as_list_loop(in_arr)

print(out_arr2)
# [[list([5, 0]) list([3, 3]) list([7, 3])]
#  [list([5, 2]) list([4, 7]) list([6, 8])]]
print(out_arr2.shape)
# (2, 3)
print(out_arr2.dtype)
# object
```

But the timings for this last are not exactly spectacular:

```py
%timeit last_dim_as_list(in_arr)
# 2.53 µs ± 37.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
%timeit last_dim_as_list_loop(in_arr)
# 12.2 µs ± 21.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

---

The `view`-based approach [proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57957137/5218354) by @PaulPanzer is very elegant and more efficient than the trick proposed in `last_dim_as_list()` because it loops (internally) through the array only once as compared to twice:

```
def last_dim_as_tuple(arr):
    dtype = [(str(i), arr.dtype) for i in range(arr.shape[-1])]
    return arr.view(dtype)[..., 0].astype(object)
```

and therefore the timings on large enough inputs are more favorable:

```py
in_arr = np.random.random((6602, 3176, 2))


%timeit last_dim_as_list(in_arr)
# 4.9 s ± 73.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit last_dim_as_tuple(in_arr)
# 3.07 s ± 117 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 0):

A vectorized approach (it's a bit tricky):

```
mat = np.random.rand(6602, 3176, 2)

f = np.vectorize(lambda x:tuple(*x.items()), otypes=[np.ndarray])
mat2 = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x:dict([tuple(x)]), 2, mat)
mat2 = np.vstack(f(mat2))
```

```
mat2.shape
Out: (6602, 3176)

type(mat2[0,0])
Out: tuple
```

Comment: This seems to be quite inefficient though. Could you perhaps explain the idea behind the steps you perform?

Comment: @norok2, yes it is indeed. It creates dict proxy in the third axis in order to reduce it   as a tuple. And I did this because converting to tuple only by using `np.apply_along_axis(lambda x:tuple(x), 2, mat)` ignore the tuple type and return a copy of the input array.