# Combine 2 2D numpy array element-wise, same shape, while retaining their shape

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Combining each element from the first array and second array and create a new array while retaining the same shape.

```
#Numpy Array 1 -- shape 7 X 5 
#X coordinates
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]])
#Numpy Array 2 -- shape 7 X 5
#Y coordinates
 array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
       [5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
       [6, 6, 6, 6, 6]])
```

Desired output should be an array of tuples.

```
#Desired Output -- shape 7 X 5
#(X,Y) combination
array([[(0,0), (1,0), (2,0), (3,0), (4,0)],
       [(0,1), (1,1), (2,1), (3,1), (4,1)],
       [(0,2), (1,2), (2,2), (3,2), (4,2)],
       [(0,3), (1,3), (2,3), (3,3), (4,3)],
       [(0,4), (1,4), (2,4), (3,4), (4,4)],
       [(0,5), (1,5), (2,5), (3,5), (4,5)],
       [(0,6), (1,6), (2,6), (3,6), (4,6)]])
```

Comment: Why does it have to be tuples? (as opposed to (7,5,2) 3d array?)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]])
#Numpy Array 2 -- shape 7 X 5
#Y coordinates
arr2 = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
       [5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
       [6, 6, 6, 6, 6]])

comb = np.vstack(([arr1.T], [arr2.T])).T
print(comb)
```

Although it is not array of tuples, but gives almost the same results.

You can add steps afterwards to get an array of tuples in the following way:

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]])
#Numpy Array 2 -- shape 7 X 5
#Y coordinates
arr2 = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
       [5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
       [6, 6, 6, 6, 6]])

comb = np.vstack(([arr1.T], [arr2.T])).T

f = np.vectorize(lambda x:tuple(*x.items()), otypes=[np.ndarray])
res = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x:dict([tuple(x)]), 2, comb)
mat2 = np.vstack(f(res))
```

This will give the following:

```
[[(0, 0) (1, 0) (2, 0) (3, 0) (4, 0)]
 [(0, 1) (1, 1) (2, 1) (3, 1) (4, 1)]
 [(0, 2) (1, 2) (2, 2) (3, 2) (4, 2)]
 [(0, 3) (1, 3) (2, 3) (3, 3) (4, 3)]
 [(0, 4) (1, 4) (2, 4) (3, 4) (4, 4)]
 [(0, 5) (1, 5) (2, 5) (3, 5) (4, 5)]
 [(0, 6) (1, 6) (2, 6) (3, 6) (4, 6)]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`dstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html#numpy.dstack) as follows: (where `x` and `y` are your first and second arrays)

```
np.dstack((x,y))
```

Comment: But I need tuples inside the array. It's giving me array inside an array.

Answer (score 0):

stealing from [Convert 3d numpy array into a 2d numpy array (where contents are tuples)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57955264/convert-3d-numpy-array-into-a-2d-numpy-array-where-contents-are-tuples) :

```
import numpy as np

#Numpy Array 1 -- shape 7 X 5 
#X coordinates
ar1 = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]])
#Numpy Array 2 -- shape 7 X 5
#Y coordinates
ar2 = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
       [5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
       [6, 6, 6, 6, 6]])
       

comb = np.stack((ar1,ar2), axis = 2)

print(comb, comb.shape , comb.dtype,'\n\n')


import numpy.lib.recfunctions as nlr

comb2 = nlr.unstructured_to_structured(comb).astype('O')

print(comb2, comb2.shape, comb2.dtype)

print(type(comb2[0,0]))
```

output :

```
[[[0 0]
  [1 0]
  [2 0]
  [3 0]
  [4 0]]

 .....
 .....
 [[0 6]
  [1 6]
  [2 6]
  [3 6]
  [4 6]]] (7, 5, 2) int64


[[(0, 0) (1, 0) (2, 0) (3, 0) (4, 0)]
 [(0, 1) (1, 1) (2, 1) (3, 1) (4, 1)]
 [(0, 2) (1, 2) (2, 2) (3, 2) (4, 2)]
 [(0, 3) (1, 3) (2, 3) (3, 3) (4, 3)]
 [(0, 4) (1, 4) (2, 4) (3, 4) (4, 4)]
 [(0, 5) (1, 5) (2, 5) (3, 5) (4, 5)]
 [(0, 6) (1, 6) (2, 6) (3, 6) (4, 6)]] (7, 5) object
<class 'tuple'>
```

The relevant part is

```
import numpy.lib.recfunctions as nlr

comb2 = nlr.unstructured_to_structured(array).astype('O')
```

cames from :

[numpy.lib.recfunctions.unstructured_to_structured(arr, dtype=None, names=None, align=False, copy=False, casting='unsafe')](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.rec.html#numpy.lib.recfunctions.unstructured_to_structured)

```
numpy.lib.recfunctions.unstructured_to_structured(arr, dtype=None, names=None, align=False, copy=False, casting='unsafe')[source]

Converts an n-D unstructured array into an (n-1)-D structured array.

The last dimension of the input array is converted into a structure, with number of field-elements equal to the size of the last dimension of the input array. By default all output fields have the input array’s dtype, but an output structured dtype with an equal number of fields-elements can be supplied instead.

Nested fields, as well as each element of any subarray fields, all count towards the number of field-elements.

Parameters:

    arr
    ndarray

        Unstructured array or dtype to convert.
    dtype
    dtype, optional

        The structured dtype of the output array
    names
    list of strings, optional

        If dtype is not supplied, this specifies the field names for the output dtype, in order. The field dtypes will be the same as the input array.
    align
    boolean, optional

        Whether to create an aligned memory layout.
    copy
    bool, optional

        See copy argument to numpy.ndarray.astype. If true, always return a copy. If false, and dtype requirements are satisfied, a view is returned.
    casting
    {‘no’, ‘equiv’, ‘safe’, ‘same_kind’, ‘unsafe’}, optional

        See casting argument of numpy.ndarray.astype. Controls what kind of data casting may occur.

Returns:

    structured
    ndarray

        Structured array with fewer dimensions.
```