# How to turn 3D image matrix to 2d matrix without a for loop? Python and numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Currently working on a lab from a Data course at school. What I want to do is convert matrix_a with shape (26,64,64) to a new matrix_b (64,1664).
The (64,64) inside matrix_a is the bits that make up a series of images, and the (64,1664) matrix_b should result in a strip of the images.
I tried using np.reshape, which does reshape the matrix correctly, but the images are lost due to the ordering used. I could use a for loop to iteratively insert each 64x64 image into matrix_b, yet they're asking that you do not use a for loop. They mentioned something about using splicing?
I'm writing this in python with numpy.
Apologies if this post makes no sense it's my first one.
Thanks

Comment: Can you please post the code you tried?

Comment: What 26,64,64 matrix represents? 64x64 image on 26 different time steps or something different? You should provide some insights about the matrix representations.

Comment: Please read [mre].

Comment: Related:[numpy with python: convert 3d array to 2d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32838802/numpy-with-python-convert-3d-array-to-2d),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> a = np.arange(2*2*3).reshape(3,2,2)
>>> a
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 2,  3]],

       [[ 4,  5],
        [ 6,  7]],

       [[ 8,  9],
        [10, 11]]])
```

Concatenate each image.

Horizontal strip - which is what you asked for in the question.

```
>>> np.concatenate(list(a),-1)
array([[ 0,  1,  4,  5,  8,  9],
       [ 2,  3,  6,  7, 10, 11]])
```

Vertical strip

```
>>> np.concatenate(list(a),0)
array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 2,  3],
       [ 4,  5],
       [ 6,  7],
       [ 8,  9],
       [10, 11]])
>>>
```

`np.hstack(tuple(a))` and `np.vstack(tuple(a))` produce identical results to `concatenate`.

`np.vsplit(a,a.shape[0])` is *equivalent* to `list(a)` or `tuple(a)`.

Answer (score 1):

With numpy, you can try this (assume data_3d is your 3d array):

```
data_2d = data_3d.swapaxes(1,2).reshape(3,-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
```

```
arr = np.random.randint(10, size= [26,64,64])
arr.shape

>>> (26, 64, 64)
```

`transpose()` reorders axes from `[0, 1, 2]` to `[1, 0, 2]`.

```
arr = arr.transpose([1,0,2])   # edit suggested by @wwii 
arr.shape

>>> (64, 64, 26)
```

```
arr = arr.reshape([64, -1])
arr.shape

>>> (64, 1664)
```

Comment: OP wants a 2d array with the 26 64x64 images *concatenated*.

Comment: @wwii "and the (64,1664) matrix_b should result in a strip of the images" exact words of OP

Comment: The shape might be correct but does the data come out correct? Try it with (4,3,3) array - `a = np.arange(3*3*4).reshape(4,3,3)`.

Comment: `arr..transpose([1,0,2])` looks better.

Comment: @wwii yeah the `transpose()` takes care of that. OP wasnt specific about how he wanted to strip data column wise or row wise, thus two options for `transpose()`