# Flatten incremental numpy values with wrong shape

Tags: python, pandas, matlab, numpy

I have 25 years of hourly-sampled in a long numpy array, in the shape (365, 24, 25).
This is data from 1975-01-01 00:00:00 to 1999-12-31 23:59:00

```
[[[0, 0.1, 0.2, ...], [0.3, 0.2, 0.2, ...], ...]]
```

Now I would like to flatten it into the dimensions (1x219000) and later put them into a dataframe looking like this:

```
1975-01-01 00:00:00    0
1975-01-01 02:00:00    0.1
1975-01-01 03:00:00    0.2
1975-01-02 01:00:00    0.2
```

I just tried to flatten it like this:

```
data1d = data.flatten()
df = pd.DataFrame(oneDimensionalData)

df.index = pd.date_range(start=pd.to_datetime('1975-01-01 00:00:00'), end=pd.to_datetime("1999-12-31 23:59:00"), periods=219000).to_series()
```

and it yielded the desired vector, but I think the order is wrong and not in continuous time since 1975.

Does anyone with more experience in flattening these 3D matrices have an idea how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [np.transpose()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32838802) to rearrange dimensions.

```
import numpy as np

# test data in ydh ordering
data_ydh = np.array(range(365*24*25)).reshape((25,365,24))
data_ydh[0,0,:]  # check y=d=0, the first 24 hours
Out[43]:
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23])

# ydh to dhy
data_dhy = data_ydh.transpose((1,2,0))
data_dhy[0,:,0]  # d=0 and y=0
Out[47]:
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23])

# dhy to ydh
data_ydh_back = data_dhy.transpose((2,0,1))
data_ydh_back[0,0]
Out[49]:
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23])
```

Comment: Much appreciated. For later people looking at this: In Matlab it can be done with permute (like transpose here)