# I must pass two-dimensional input. Three-dimensional list to dataframe (Python)

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

[image]

I'm web scraping data and want to put it into a data frame for analysis.

I have a three-dimensional list that comes out of my scrape and I can't figure out how to get it into a data frame. I know I need to make it two-dimensional (249, 4) from the three-dimensional list (1, 249, 4).

```
table_countryCodes = pd.read_html("https://www.iban.com/country-codes")
np.reshape(table_countryCodes, (249,4))
df_countryCodes = pd.DataFrame(table_countryCodes)
print(df_countryCodes)
```

> Error: ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=(1, 249, 4)

How can I fix this?

Here is a sample of the three-dimensional list from the web scrape for context:

[image]

```
Country            Alpha-2 code   Alpha-3 code   Numeric
American Samoa        AS             ASM            16
Andorra               AD             AND            20
Angola                AO             AGO            24
Anguilla              AI             AIA            660
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [numpy with python: convert 3d array to 2d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32838802/numpy-with-python-convert-3d-array-to-2d)

Comment: I try running that but I get an error when using the transpose function "'list' object has no attribute 'transpose'"

Comment: can you print the 3d list here as raw text

Comment: Please format and post it in the question itself

Comment: I will do - I'm struggling to do that though. One moment.

Comment: formatted as best I could, thank you for your help

Comment: You don't have a 3D array, its a 2D array only

Comment: Okay, then how do I convert from 2d array to dataframe? I thought pd.dataframe would do it no?

Comment: I added a picture from the spyder ide. It says the type is a list but the valu e is a dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pd.read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) reads all HTML tables into a list of DataFrame objects. Since your use case has only *one* table in the page, you can extract the same using

```
df = table_countryCodes[0]
print(df)
```

which gives us

```
               Country Alpha-2 code Alpha-3 code  Numeric
0          Afghanistan           AF          AFG        4
1        Åland Islands           AX          ALA      248
2              Albania           AL          ALB        8
3              Algeria           DZ          DZA       12
4       American Samoa           AS          ASM       16
..                 ...          ...          ...      ...
244  Wallis and Futuna           WF          WLF      876
245     Western Sahara           EH          ESH      732
246              Yemen           YE          YEM      887
247             Zambia           ZM          ZMB      894
248           Zimbabwe           ZW          ZWE      716

[249 rows x 4 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply need:

```
pd.DataFrame(table_countryCodes[0])
```

i.e. add `[0]` to select the first and only element in `table_countryCodes`, which has the shape you need.